# What is this thing that brings Nicky back to life?

Tags: plot-explanation, focus

In Focus (2015) Owens shoots Nicky in the rib, and he puts this thing and sucks it to bring him alive.

[image]

So what's this thing?

Comment: Haven't seen it yet, but any chance his lung collapsed and he perforated it to fix this problem? At least I remember something similar from one ER episode.

Comment: Didn't see it. But a broken ribs can cause blood to enter the lungs, and it can act as a syringe to remove it. Or maybe just to get air pass (if it's not the in the lung, directly) because of suffocation, or maybe a thing with adrenaline (usually into heart I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device that is used to remove blood from Nicky's lungs is called a [**Metal Oil Suction Syringe**](http://m.sitebox.ltd.uk/sealey-ak46-oil-suction-syringe-500ml-metal-body-osealey_AK46#.V9n2-D9lDmw) This is used by auto mechanics for the removal of oil from gearboxes and differentials like the one shown below:

[image: Metal oil syringe]

Nicky was more than likely suffering from [Pulmonary Contusion](https://www.drugs.com/cg/pulmonary-contusion.html), which is treatable with a chest tube and/or suctioning as is shown (rather loosely) in the movie with the metal suctioning syringe.  Also, Nicky wasn't dead, so there was no "bringing him alive"

> **Suctioning**: This is done to remove any blood or mucus that is
>   blocking your air passages. Caregivers may insert a tube connected to
>   a suction machine into your mouth, nasal passages, or ET tube.
>
> **Chest tube:** A chest tube is used to remove air, blood, or fluid from around your lungs or heart. This lets your lungs fill with air
>   when you breathe, and helps your heart beat normally. A tube may be
>   inserted through an incision in your chest to drain the air or fluid.
>   The chest tube is attached to a container to collect the blood or
>   fluid.

Of course, this is Hollywood and the chances of this scenario being successful are slim to none.